# Neo4j browser can't fully connect to embedded instance

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-bolt, neo4j-embedded, neo4j-browser

I'm trying to connect to a neo4j embedded instance with the neo4j browser but when I try to connect the browser just displays "Connecting..." forever and the following error is shown in the browser console: `Uncaught Error: Bolt V2 should always support byte arrays`. What could cause this?

Comment: I am facing the very same issue. I wonder if you have any progress on that?

Comment: Nope :( It seems like neo4j-community is needed instead.

Comment: Upgrading to 1.7 seems to solve the problem

Comment: it hasn't for me, anybody else have any solutions?